# Rover is composing supergraph with unexpected character

Tags: apollo, apollo-federation

I'm following the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/gateway/#composing-the-supergraph-schema) trying to get an apollo gateway up and running. I'm using rover to compose my subgraph with this command: `rover supergraph compose --config ./supergraph-config.yaml > supergraph.graphql`

The command works, however when I try to start up my gateway, I get this error: `GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Unexpected character: U+FFFD.` It seems the supergraph compose command is adding some invalid chatacters for some reason. When I print out the file as a string I see these 2 characters at the top of the file: ��.

Example:

```
��
schema
  @link(url: "https://specs.apollo.dev/link/v1.0")
  @link(url: "https://specs.apollo.dev/join/v0.2", for: EXECUTION)
{
  query: Query
}
...
```

I also haven't been able to find any issues on stack overflow or github so I'm not really sure what the issue is.

Gateway:

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');
const { ApolloGateway } = require('@apollo/gateway');
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
const path = require("path");

const schemaString = readFileSync("../supergraph.graphql").toString()
const supergraphSdl = gql` ${schemaString} `;

// Initialize an ApolloGateway instance and pass it
// the supergraph schema
const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
  supergraphSdl,
});

// Pass the ApolloGateway to the ApolloServer constructor
const server = new ApolloServer({
  gateway,
});

server.listen().then(() => {
  console.log(` Gateway ready `);
});
```

Subgraph:

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');
const { buildSubgraphSchema } = require('@apollo/subgraph');

interface User {
    id: string
    username: string
}

const typeDefs = gql`
  extend schema
    @link(url: "https://specs.apollo.dev/federation/v2.0",
          import: ["@key", "@shareable"])

  type Query {
    me: User
  }

  type User @key(fields: "id") {
    id: ID!
    username: String
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    me() {
      return { id: "1", username: "@ava" }
    }
  },
  User: {
    __resolveReference(user: User, { fetchUserById }: any){
      return fetchUserById(user.id)
    }
  }
}

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema: buildSubgraphSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers })
});

server.listen(3000).then(({ url }) => {
    console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file that rover was generating was encoded in utf16le, the problem was that I was reading the file in utf8.

Reading the file in 'utf16le' encoding format worked.

```
const schemaString = await readFileSync('../supergraph.graphql', 'utf16le');
```

Comment: Is this missing in apollo federation documentation?

Comment: I believe so, couldn't find anything anywhere in the federation docs or rover docs.